# PHPMailer a href link in HTML mail isn't working correct

Tags: php, html, smtp, html-email, phpmailer

I got this code:

```
$userid = 123456;
    $plaintext  = "
    Klicke auf den folgenden Link um deine Anmeldung bei xxx zu bestÃ¤tigen:
    http://xxx.de/confirm.php?id=" . $userid;

    $html = '
    Klicke auf den folgenden Link um deine Anmeldung bei xxx zu bestÃ¤tigen:
    <br><br>
    <a href="http://xxx.de/confirm.php?id=' . $userid . '">Anmeldung abschliessen</a>';


    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->setLanguage('de', 'language/');
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "xxx";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxx';
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->From = 'kontakt@xxx.de';
    $mail->FromName = 'xxx';
    $mail->addAddress($email, $email);
    $mail->addReplyTo('kontakt@xxx.de', 'xxx');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $nickname . ' - BestÃ¤tige deine Anmeldung';
    $mail->Body    = $html;
    $mail->AltBody = $plaintext;
    $mail->send();
```

The link works correct in the plain text mail but not in the HTML version, the link becomes something like: xxx.de/?id=fdfafdafadfadfargagga
So the ints are becoming endless letters and the `confirm.php` part disappears. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Apperently it's the mandrill email service fault

Comment: Hmmn I'm not sure about this, but what you can try is instead of directing it to `confirm.php`, you can transfer `confirm.php` into a folder named 'confirm' and rename `confirm.php`, which is now inside the folder named 'confirm', to `index.php`. which means your link should look like this now: `http://xxx.de/confirm/?id=user_id_here1234`. This will of course require apache `DirectoryIndex` to be set to index.php but that is usually the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed your email processors fault. The tidiest way to fix this is to set up a rewrite on your web server. If you're using apache, you could do this in your apache config file or a `.htacccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^/confirm/([0-9]+) /confirm.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite URLs like `http://xxx.de/confirm/1234` (which should be left alone by the email handler) to `http://xxx.de/confirm.php?id=1234`, which is what your script is expecting. In your template you'd rearrange it to look like the first form:

```
$html = 'Klicke auf den folgenden Link um deine Anmeldung bei xxx zu bestÃ¤tigen:<br><br>
<a href="http://xxx.de/confirm/' . $userid . '">Anmeldung abschliessen</a>';
```

and it looks like you have a little encoding problem to deal with too...